# Visual studio - Xamarin iOS remote simulator hot reload initialized correctly but not working

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, hot-reload

I am working on the iOS version of my Xamarin app. I've updated all frameworks and VS to latest version so I am currently running `Visual Studio 16.7.7` and `Xamarin iOS SDK 14.2.0.12`. I am able to start the app and work with it using the remote simulator. But I am not able to use the Hot reload feature. I am correctly set up with the option enabled in VS and have the build option set to "Don't link".

Here the related debug output :

```
[HotReload] (2020-11-05 10:35:39.0): INFO: (ProjectName.iOS) (HotReloadAgent) HotReload: Initialized Agent.
[HotReload] (2020-11-05 10:35:41.7): INFO: XAML Hot Reload is connected and ready.
```

Then I update some Xaml...:

```
[HotReload] (2020-11-05 10:38:01.3): INFO: (ProjectName.iOS) Xaml Changed for 'Views/ViewName.xaml' in 'ProjectName', sending to app...
```

But nothing happens in the simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems an issue of IDE . Post it to **Help->Send feedback -> Report a problem** .

Comment: Thanks @LucasZhang-MSFT for the suggestion. For the ones interested:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1245934/visual-studio-xamarin-ios-remote-simulator-hot-rel.html